# Disk encryption in linux

Tags: linux

because of audit it is necessary to encrypt the data in the database (elasticsearch) I am an absolute noob in encryption after a little googling, I realized that there is encryption at the disk level (when you need to enter a master password or use the TPM module when loading the OS) and then ENTIRE disk is decrypted and second type of encryption exists at the file system level, this is when each file or partition encrypts / decrypts data on the fly

it is also recommended to use dm_crypt in conjunction with LUKS, but somewhere they write that LUKS uses dm_crypt under the hood and is intended only for encrypting the entire disk (that is, when the OS starts, all data is decrypted), and somewhere they write that LUKS is encryption at the block device level, and dm_crypt encrypts/decrypts files on the fly

I need both mechanisms or at least encryption at the FS level can i use LUKS for block level encryption ( after boot ) and file encryption on the fly using dm_crypt?

Comment: Disk encryption only matters when the system is off or the disk is removed and I doubt that is the problem the audit is bringing up. You need to speak with your auditor and understand what data they want encrypting.

Comment: @Mokubai Encryption at rest is a frequent demand in corporate environments. It is not at all unlikely this is actually what’s needed.

Comment: @DanielB judging by their new question it would appear that data at rest is not their problem, it is live data security: https://superuser.com/questions/1735124/protect-files-from-copying-and-reading-linux

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross posted to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712220/disk-encryption-in-linux. Please read [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/).

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, LUKS is just a wrapper around *dm-crypt*. It handles some plumbing and how strong keys are stored and encrypted using the user password.

Under the hood, it’s still *dm-crypt*. It is *transparent encryption* (what you call encrypt/decrypt on the fly). *dm-crypt* operates on block devices (whole devices or partitions) only. It is not aware of higher-level concepts like filesystems or even files and directories.

With block encryption, it would not be feasible to decrypt all data on boot. *Decrypting* (reading, decrypting, writing) all data takes hours on most storage devices. Unfortunately, informal speech is rarely accurate. Data is not decrypted. Instead, the encryption is “unlocked” (meaning the encryption key is loaded).

*dm-crypt*, with or without LUKS, is very similar to TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt/BitLocker.

The alternative would be file-based transparent encryption, for example eCryptfs or EncFS. It is probably not suitable for database files.

Comment: If I remember correctly, even TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt on Linux just uses dm-crypt. (Cryptsetup's own tcrypt/bitlk support is of course also dm-crypt-based.)

Comment: Thanks for explanation! i have audit requirement that if i copy files from my disk, they doesn't will read, what encryption method should i use?

Comment: None of these. For that you need encryption at the application layer. Both of these techniques are only effective if the encryption is not unlocked. Otherwise, files are just files.

Answer (score 1):

> I realized that there is encryption at the disk level (when you need to enter a master password or use the TPM module when loading the OS) and then ENTIRE disk is decrypted and second type of encryption exists at the file system level, this is when each file or partition encrypts / decrypts data on the fly

This is not entirely correct.

I assume you were thinking that disk-level encryption will decrypt the entire disk at once, while filesystem-level encryption will decrypt an entire file at once – but neither of those is true. Both filesystem and whole-disk encryption work at sector level, and they're almost equally "on the fly".

The entire disk is certainly *not* decrypted when loading the OS – doing so could take several hours (read each sector, process it, write it back), and then you'd need to encrypt it again on shutdown, taking several more hours.

So instead, encryption at the disk level is always done "on the fly" – it might *look* like the device is decrypted because you can access all files, but really the filesystem is running on top of an additional layer that decrypts **individual sectors** on-demand.

In LUKS, for example, "dm-crypt" is actually the **block-device level** on-the-fly encryption layer – the "LUKS" part (cryptsetup) only handles prompting for passphrase, reading the TPM, decrypting the disk's master key; but then it loads the key into dm-crypt which creates a virtual "decrypted" device. When you unlock a LUKS-encrypted disk, you're always dealing with the virtual "/dev/mapper/foo" device provided by dm-crypt – it provides the on-the-fly encryption and decryption while the physical "/dev/sda" device remains fully encrypted.

So what you've read about LUKS is not contradictory – it is block-level *and* it is on-the-fly.

(Also, in most cases you can just assume that "LUKS" and "dm-crypt" refer to the same product. It is not possible to use LUKS without dm-crypt, and although it would be *technically* possible for you to use dm-crypt without LUKS you'd still have to do the same things LUKS does, so 'recommended' is a bit of understatement. Normally, the *only* time you'd use dm-crypt without LUKS is if you were trying to open a BitLocker or TCRYPT volume on Linux.)

Partition encryption is *not* "file encryption" – instead it's actually the same thing as disk encryption, i.e. it's still block-level but only confined to the start/end of a single partition. In fact, many "whole disk" encryption systems encrypt individual partitions and not actually the whole disk.

For example, when enabling BitLocker on C:, only the main system partition gets encrypted while the "EFI System Partition" (and any other partitions on the disk) remain open. This is needed because the software that *actually unlocks* BitLocker (i.e. reads TPM, prompts for password) lives on the same disk within the EFI System Partition – the decryption tool cannot itself be encrypted. Similarly, for LUKS, at minimum the bootloader (GRUB) must remain unencrypted.

(For purely data disks, LUKS can be used to be encrypt either the entire disk *or* the individual partitions – it doesn't care, as both disks and partitions are block-based devices.)

So in short, your last question is based on wrong assumptions and cannot be answered properly. Most likely you don't need both mechanisms as they're actually the same mechanism – again, encryption at block device level *is* on-the-fly, you use the same method to achieve both. (On Linux this generally means LUKS/dm-crypt; on Windows this means either BitLocker or some expensive corporate-mandated thing.)

That being said, filesystem encryption does exist, but it uses completely different tools, not dm-crypt. (It also is more dependent on the filesystem in question, and cannot be used for encrypting OS files.) For example, NTFS on Windows supports file-level encryption via "EFS", while some Linux filesystems support "fscrypt".